# replicate json encoded assoc array?

Tags: php, json

I have a json string

```
{
   "to": {
      "data": [
         {
            "name": "f8",
            "id": "11204705797"
         },
         {
            "name": "f9",
            "id": "11205705797"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and I need to replicate it in php, what I have is a array of name&id's like this

```
Array
(
    [friends] => Array
        (
            [0] => 939394934-Steve
            [1] => 939394934-Steve
            [2] => 939394934-Steve
            [3] => 939394934-Steve
        )

)
```

and I would explode by - to get id-name

How can I do this?

Comment: oh really? No but seriously, how can I get this assoc array into a properly formatted array that I can json_encode to get a replicate of the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($array['friends'] as $friend) {
    list($id, $name) = explode('-', $friend, 2);
    $data[] = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'id' => $id,
    );
}

$to = new stdClass; // 'to' appears to be an object... because of {}
$to->data = $data;
echo json_encode(array('to'=>$to));
```